# PHP Return portion of path

Tags: php

I have a path like this:

```
../../images/trades/general/banners/header3.jpg
```

How could I return the last two directories and the filename as a single string?
I am looking to return "general/banners/header3.jpg".  Keeping in mind that the directories can vary as well as the filename.

Thank you!
Rick

Comment: explode() on slash, array_slice() with a negative offset to get the last three entries, then implode() on slash.

Comment: A downvote? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '../../images/trades/general/banners/header3.jpg';
echo lastPortionOfPath($string);

function lastPortionOfPath($string, $segments= 3) {
    $chunks = explode('/', $string);
    $chunks = array_slice($chunks, count($chunks) - $segments, $segments);

    return implode('/', $chunks);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Matt!

Answer (score 1):

```
$chain = "../../images/trades/general/banners/header3.jpg";
/*
*  All this regex do the same thing
*
$regex = "/^.+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/";
$regex = "/^.+((\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+){3}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/";
$regex = "/^.+((\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+){3}\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/";
*/
```

Create the regex string that match your need

```
$regex = "/^.+((\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+){3}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/";
```

parentheses are use to catch everything that match the regex in the parentheses and all that values can be retrieve by using the third value of the `preg_match` function which in this case is `$matches`

```
if(preg_match( $regex, $chain, $matches)){
    // $result will be equal to "/general/banners/header3.jpg"
    $result = substr($matches[1], 1, strlen($matches[1]) - 1); // remove the first /
}
echo $result; // general/banners/header3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

The path

```
$path = "../../images/trades/general/banners/header3.jpg";
```

Separate the string by slash

```
$path = explode('/',$path);
```

Read the size of the generated array and subtract 3 because this is the number of portions you want(1 file + 2 directories):

```
$pathSize=count($path)-3;
$newPath = $path[$pathSize].'/'.$path[$pathSize+1].'/'.$path[$[pathSize+2];
```

Shows the result

```
echo 'Result: '.$newPath;
```